# Unable to restart CDC after making table changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cdc

I need to add a couple of columns to CDC for a table that is already being tracked. My approach is as follows:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_drop_job 'capture'

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
    -- Copy existing data of the tracked table into a temporary table
    SELECT * INTO CDC.dbo_MyTable_Temp FROM CDC.dbo_MyTable_CT

    -- Add the new column to the temp table. This allows us to just use INSERT..SELECT * later
    ALTER TABLE CDC.dbo_MyTable_Temp ADD MyColumn INT NULL

    -- Disable CDC for the source table temporarily. This will drop the CDC table
    EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table @source_schema = 'dbo', @source_name = 'MyTable', @capture_instance = 'dbo_MyTable'

    -- Reenable CDC for the source table. This will recreate the table with the new columns
    EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = 'dbo', @source_name = 'MyTable', @capture_instance = 'dbo_MyTable', @supports_net_changes = 1, @role_name = NULL, @filegroup_name = 'CDCGROUP'

    -- Insert the old values into the CDC table
    INSERT INTO cdc.dbo_MyTable_CT SELECT * FROM cdc.dbo_MyTable_Temp

    -- Correct the start_lsn in CDC.change_tables. Otherwise all of the CDC stored procedures will be confused
    -- and although the old data will exist in the table the functions won't return it
    UPDATE cdc.change_tables SET start_lsn = (SELECT MIN(__$start_lsn) FROM cdc.dbo_MyTable_Temp) WHERE capture_instance = 'dbo_MyTable'

    -- Drop the temp table
    DROP TABLE cdc.dbo_MyTable_Temp

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR('Error!', 16, 1)
END CATCH

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_add_job 'capture'
```

However, when the job runs again after being re-added it generates an error that there is a violation of the primary key constraint on `CDC.lsn_time_mapping`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get to the exact cause of the error because the updates to the `lsn_time_mapping` happen in an extended stored procedure, but I was able to use different code to add the columns. Basically, I stuck to the CDC stored procedures instead of doing `ALTER TABLE` commands on the CDC table. The code is below:

```
-- Create a new capture instance for the table
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = 'dbo', @source_name = 'MyTable', @capture_instance = 'dbo_MyTable_New', @supports_net_changes = 1, @role_name = NULL, @filegroup_name = 'CDCGROUP'

-- Copy all of the existing data from the old capture instance
INSERT INTO CDC.dbo_MyTable_New_CT SELECT *, NULL AS NewColumn1, NULL AS NewColumn2 FROM CDC.dbo_MyTable_CT

-- Disable the old capture instance
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table @source_schema = 'dbo', @source_name = 'MyTable', @capture_instance = 'dbo_MyTable'

-- Now we need to jump through some hoops to rename the capture instance back to what it was:
-- Recreate a new capture instance with the old name again
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = 'dbo', @source_name = 'MyTable', @capture_instance = 'dbo_MyTable', @supports_net_changes = 1, @role_name = NULL, @filegroup_name = 'CDCGROUP'

-- Copy all of the data over again
INSERT INTO CDC.dbo_MyTable_CT SELECT * FROM CDC.dbo_MyTable_New_CT

-- Remove the capture instance that we had been using to add the new columns
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table @source_schema = 'dbo', @source_name = 'MyTable', @capture_instance = 'dbo_MyTable_New'

-- We need to correct the start_lsn in the cdc.change_tables table. Otherwise all of the CDC stored procedures and views will be confused and
-- although the old data will exist in the CDC table it wouldn't be returned by those CDC procs
UPDATE cdc.change_tables SET start_lsn = (SELECT MIN(__$start_lsn) FROM cdc.dbo_MyTable_CT) WHERE capture_instance = 'dbo_MyTable'
```

Note that I'm performing this during downtime of the database. If you need to do this while the database is in use then you may need to add `WHERE` clauses to your insert statements so that you don't copy the same record from one table into a table where it already exists. When both capture instances are active any DML that affects the table **will** put rows into both capture instances.